# How to use same DTO foreign key relationship for table and view

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using ORMLite and I have a foreign key relationship defined between an invoice DTO and invoice line DTO:

```
public interface IDto<PKType> where PKType : struct
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Id is required")]
    PKType Id { get; set; }
}

[Ss.Alias("Invoices")]    
public class InvoiceDto : AuditedDto, IAuditedDto, IDto<Guid>
{
    [Required]
    public Guid VendorId { get; set; }

    [Ss.Reference]
    public List<InvoiceLineDto> InvoiceLines { get; set; }
}

[Ss.Alias("InvoiceLines")]
public class InvoiceLineDto : AuditedDto, IAuditedDto, IDto<Guid>
{
    [Required]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Qty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [Ss.ForeignKey(typeof(InvoiceDto))]
    public Guid InvoiceId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have defined a view across my invoices that returns the same data but includes the invoice status:

```
[Ss.Alias("InvoiceStatus")]    
public class InvoiceStatusDto : InvoiceDto
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

But when I query the `InvoiceStatus` view this gives a `System.ArgumentException: Cant find 'InvoiceStatusId' Property on Type 'InvoiceLineDto'`. I'm unsure how to address this short of duplicating the `InvoiceLineDto` specifically to define the foreign key relationship. Is there some way to handle this situation using code instead of annotations perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

OrmLite [foreign key](https://ayende.com/blog/4769/code-review-guidelines-avoid-inheritance-for-properties) and [references attributes relies on naming conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-support-poco-style). The issue is that the `InvoiceLines` table maintains a foreign key to the `Invoices` table not the `InvoiceStatus` table.

You're doing a disservice by trying to overly use Inheritance in your Data Models for presumably some pursuit of DRY. OrmLite's POCO Data Models should map 1:1 to RDBMS tables, the use of multiple levels of inheritance suggests this isn't the case or if it is the underlying RDBMS has an unnecessary explosion of tables.

Whilst it should be a goal to DRY your implementation logic where it doesn't cause coupling conflicts, this does not apply to your POCOs or Schema definitions...

#### Hiding Properties by abusing Inheritance

[Hiding properties isn't duplicating code](https://ayende.com/blog/4769/code-review-guidelines-avoid-inheritance-for-properties), it's making the intent clear. Properties are declarative, hiding them just makes it harder to read and reason about your code which requires having to open multiple source files and puts the burden on the developer reading your code and increases their cognitive load required by forcing them to merge and construct the schema from multiple source files in their head instead of them being able to look at a single source file with all the properties of the table explicitly listed.

Multiple levels of inheritance in Data Models is an abuse of inheritance where I suspect it's the cause of tight coupling issues and poor RDBMS design. I don't see how you need a completely separate `InvoiceStatus` table instead of maintaining a single `Invoice` table that includes the `Status` field.

Other issues with your table structure is the `Dto` suffix which denotes these are DTOs not data models. Whilst it's [perfectly reasonable to reuse OrmLite's Data Model classes as DTOs](http://docs.servicestack.net/service-complexity-and-dto-roles#the-simple-poco-life) the `Dto` suffix suggests you're maintaining separate purpose-specific DTO classes (i.e. for Serialization) separate from your Data Models. But this example instead adds `[ForeignKey]` attributes and to DTO classes, instead of having them on Data Model classes.

The other naming issue is that some of your RDBMS tables use inconsistent plural naming conventions with `[Ss.Alias("InvoiceLines")]` being plural whilst `[Ss.Alias("InvoiceStatus")]` is not.

Comment: Thanks for the lecture. I'm not overly using inheritance and frankly I didn't provide enough context for you to be expounding on the virtues or otherwise of my design choices. In this one situation I was hoping to be able to reuse a DTO class because regardless of the Invoices table or InvoiceStatus view, the InvoiceLines table is the same. Being unable to do that using OrmLite would appear to be a limitation of OrmLite and not something inherently wrong with the approach I'm taking. Your plural naming comment is nonsense, "InvoiceStatuses" or "InvoicesStatus" or "InvoicesStatuses", really?

Comment: @DavidClarke If you're not going to be consistent with naming why even introduce the naming mismatch with your table classes to begin with? You're left with every table needing an alias and your RDBMS tables having inconsistent naming conventions.

Comment: @DavidClarke You're comment on "short of duplicating" suggests you view declaring properties as code duplication that you're trying to use inheritance to avoid it which is what my answer is addressing that the end result is worse for readability and impacts either the design of your classes or RDBMS tables.

Comment: `InvoiceStatus` is the correct name for the table and doesn't introduce inconsistency into the database. `InvoiceStatuses` doesn't reflect the purpose of the table, nor does `InvoicesStatus` or `InvoicesStatuses`. And I need an alias regardless because I'm using Postgres. I'm *not* over-using inheritance for DTO's - this is the one place I've introduced it but you wouldn't know that because I didn't include that information because it wasn't relevant to my question. I have a table and a view that reference the same table. I was hoping I wouldn't have to duplicate that table's DTO.

Comment: Maybe it's correct for naming convention you've adopted but it isn't clear what that is as `InvoiceStatus` is not plural whereas all your other tables are. I'd be be leaving them as the same name as the classes, i.e. `Invoice`, `InvoiceLine`, `InvoiceStatus` as introducing the mismatch is a form of accidental complexity. OrmLite uses quoted table names for PostgreSQL tables, aliases are unnecessary just as they are for property names. DTOs = Data Transfer Object which would indicate these classes are only used for serialization, but it's misleading here as they're being used as Data Models.

Comment: ok, you've forced me to reference https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/877/what-is-the-plural-form-of-status. Let's just agree to disagree on the name of the table. With respect to plural versus singular table names, I prefer Joe Celko's recommended practice of "Collective or class table names are better than singular names because a table is a set and not a scalar value." So my class names will always be singular and require an alias to make the mapping to the associated table explicit.

Comment: which still doesn't answer my original question but I think it's correct to say that OrmLite doesn't support this scenario with attributes and my only option is to have 2 separate models for the InvoiceLines table.

Comment: @DavidClarke Right, the issue was addressed in the first paragraph, the Foreign Key references the Invoice table that it's attributed to with the solution being to use a separate class that maps 1:1 with the underlying table/relationships. Using plural names made more sense when everything was database first, now most ORM's are code-first with the source code representing the source of truth which you can use to infer the RDBMS table schema from.

Comment: You are conflating two unrelated things. Naming conventions for databases should respect accepted practice for databases (which also earns respect from your resident DBA). Naming conventions for classes should respect accepted practice for classes. Bridging the gap isn't about making one look like the other, it is about using what is appropriate in each context. EF prior to EF Core provided automatic pluralisation of names.

Comment: Of course they're related, the RDBMS table is a projection off the code-first data models. There's no respect to be earned for introducing accidental complexity, naming conventions are just preferences, both RDBMS tables and class names are artificial constructs apart of your overall system. If it's to adhere to existing requirements so be it, but there's no inherent benefit in relying on English pluralization rules to define names and maintain codified relationships of related artifacts. EF has to deal with brownfield DB-first models and appease traditional naming schemes, most new ORMs don't

Comment: Clearly we are on opposite sides on that debate. I accept your perspective but disagree with your conclusion.